# Linux 64ビット 1プロセス最大サイズ

Tags: linux

Linuxにおける、
多段ページングを学習しております。

リニアアドレスが48ビット制限の場合、
1プロセスがフルフルに
512×512×512×512×8バイトの512GBのテーブルを使い切ったとすると、
そのプロセスの物理メモリを食うサイズはいくつになりますでしょうか？

計算式などを知りたいと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 求めているものでは無さそうですが、実際のディストリビューションだとこんな資料があるようです。[Red Hat Enterprise Linux テクノロジーの機能と制限](https://access.redhat.com/ja/articles/1271503), [Oracle Linux: Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/oracle-linux-limits/)

Comment: こういう質問では「正確な用語」を使わないと質問者の意図を読者が理解できないので求める答えが出ないというか。物理メモリ（というかプライベートワーキングっセット）量なんて状況次第っス。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/lyhtbigom61hft と同じ人だろうか？　たかだか変換テーブルにギガバイトもメモリ使うとか本気で思っているのだろうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。